# for reminding VS in reminding

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I was writing this one sentence and confused with *prepositions*. Additionally, I would like to know if there are other grammatical errors besides these two prepositions.

....They are always helpful *for* reminding me *of* what to focus on in order to improve my English.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Oxford Dictionary definitions for the two prepositions that you proposed:

> **in** [meaning 8](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/in) - As an integral part of (an activity)
>
> **for** [meaning 4](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/for) - Having (the thing mentioned) as a purpose or function

Both prepositions are correct: **in** would focus on their involvement in your studies, and **for** would focus on their purpose.

---

If you look at the entry for remind in the [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/remind), you will see that one of the possible usages is (+ that), for example

> Remind me **that** I have to go to the dentist at 3pm.

**that** is a relative pronoun here, and you can substitute other relative pronouns: what, who why, which, etc. so it's OK to say

> ...reminding me what to focus on...

It is not necessary to add **of** before **what** in this sentence. It's not wrong to include **of**, but it sounds a little strange.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer, this was very helpful!

Comment: But to me, "in reminding" sounds a little odd because it reads like "They are always helpful **only** when reminding me of what to focus on..." For this reason, I think "for reminding" would be better.

Comment: @EvaristeGalois  "There's a fly **in** my soup", doesn't mean that the only place you'll find a fly is in my soup. it's just one place where you will definitely find one.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use either `for` or `of` in this sentence, but use commas instead :

> They are always helpful, reminding me what to focus on, in order to
>   improve my English.

Comment: I like this approach as well, thank you so much for your answer!